# Error saving game in Fallout 1

Tags: technical-issues, fallout

I recently adquired Fallout 1 along with patches 1.2, 1.3 and the High Resolution patch. I installled, patched and started to play but after 4 days I got an error.

I was searching The Glow last night (an area of the game) and I decided to save game and go to bed, but I got and error instead. Something like "Error saving game! Unable to save game". Also I was saving over an old save file, and the game deleted the old save after the error.

Does anyone know what could happened? I have advanced a lot in the game story, and I really don't feel like starting all over again.

BTW these are my PC spec's: Windows 7 32 bit, the game is installed in D and I perfomed the humungous installation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible directory permissions are in some weird state? Fallout was written back before there was directory privilege separation. You might need to take ownership of the save game directory or run as Administrator (bad idea, try to avoid this - but can be useful for testing).

Comment: Permissions are fine, I installed the game on D: (data partition) instead of C: (system partition) to avoid this conflicts.